# Why IK shoulders coming unattached when animated?

Tags: animation, rigging, bones, pose-mode, inverse-kinematics

I'm pretty new to rigging. My robot friend here has IK arms with pole targets for the elbows. He's animating nicely but his shoulders are not appearing to stay connected when dramatic spine movement is introduced. This is strangely not as noticeable while the animation is playing but is especially apparent when you slowly scrub through the timeline. It may have something to do with the fact that the Shoulder.R/L controls can be dragged away from the body with ease. The same is true for the Leg.R/L controls.

[image]

Could it be that I simply don't have them connected or parented to the other bones properly?

I tried Location Constraints on the Arm.R. No dice.

[image]

Comment: Looking at console, you have 8 dependency loops.  Fix those.

Comment: Sort of struggling with this concept. I get A is  parented to B which is parented to A, but I'm not seeing that in the rig. I'm having a hard time interpreting what I see in the console and a harder time finding information on how to fix dependency loops. I've seen solutions that amount to making both bones siblings parented to another, but I can't do that with everything of course.

Comment: Anywho! I deleted the copy rotation constraints on the shoulders, and the arms are behaving now. As far as the others are concerned, I guess I'll figure out how to deal with them as they become problems. Quite a wonky process I've got here huh? Thank you Nathan! You're my rigging Super Man! I'll be posting a question about animating that spring in his middle there soon.

Comment: With regards to dependency loops, it's a bit like debugging a program, where the best person to debug it is the one that made it, because they know how everything is supposed to fit together.  Additionally, in cases of dependency loops, it's often no easier for a stranger to understand what you want from the rig than it is for Blender-- a dependency loop usually means a slightly incoherent vision of how things are supposed to work.  But if you have a single, specific dependency loop you want to focus on, and you can describe desired behavior in plain English, I can help with that.

Comment: Good stuff. The shoulders and arms are performing just as intended currently. I wanted the shoulders to stay put relative to the spine when it moves and now they do. No other dependencies seem to be impeding my animation workflow. My next task is to figure out a method of animating the belly spring extending and contracting. I need the spring mesh to deform as a spring naturally would, and I need the upper body to go along with it. I need the spring to work in unreal engine so it should probably be a shape key based solution. That's beyond the scope of the question I asked here though.